# Using Salesforce as Service Provider for SAML With Azure B2C as Identity Provider, how can I identify what is not configured correctly?

Tags: azure, salesforce, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, saml

The past few days I have spent following this guide to setting up Azure B2C as an IDP in a SAML authentication flow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers

It was very helpful in getting me familiar with custom policies and I was able to get it working with the Microsoft Sample App as the Service Provider, but now I am struggling to figure out how to adapt what works with the Sample App to work with any real service providers that I am attempting.

Specifically, I would like to first setup Salesforce as our service provider, but am running into a wall that I am finding difficult to troubleshoot.

So far, I have created a single sign on setting in Salesforce and loaded it with the information from the metadata provided by the Azure custom policy, as well as updating the manifest for our SAML application to make the identifierUris point to the entity ID provided by the Single Sign On setting in Salesforce. The loaded data should be attempting to use the same custom policy that I was using to log in using the Sample Application and I have added the appropriate auth option to the Salesforce login page.
Now when I attempt to login through the SSO button that is on my Saleforce login page that ties to this setting, I am met with this error that I am unable to login with SSO before I am even able to enter my any credentials or met with a login screen: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX6pA.png)

Given the somewhat vague nature of the error and the lack of logging or other tools to troubleshoot, I am sort of unsure what I might still be missing to get this working correctly or where I can even find this information. I suspect one thing that I might need still is to point the SAML app in B2C at a metadata url from Salesforce, but I have been unable to track down where I might find the metadata that Salesforce is expecting to provide it. It seems likely to me that the problem is on the Azure side of things since I am not even able to get the point where I can enter my credentials for Salesforce to reject the SAML response, and since the single sign on settings were loaded directly from the custom policy meta data XML, but I can't say for sure either way which is in part why I am not sure what to try next.

We have also looked into setting it up as an OpenID Connect SSO, but would prefer to get SAML working if possible as we are also planning to connect our B2C AD with several other applications that will require we use SAML.

Curious if anyone else has run into similar issues and was able to resolve it or if there are any ways to troubleshoot this that I might be overlooking.

**Update**

Using the SAML tool recommended I was able to find that the error I was hitting is as follows:
Application registered corresponding to IssuerUri "--EntityID--" in AuthRequest does not have assertion consumer service URL "--EntityId--" specified in its metadata.

According to a forum post on the SF help [forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000ILHHQA4), the login URL of the Single Sign on Settings created in Salesforce should be the URL to use. However, when I attempted to add this URL to the replyUrlsWithType attribute in the manifest of the Azure app, I got an error on saving that a property has an invalid value.

Comment: Look in the network tab of the Chrome Dev tools. You probably will see a request go to B2C, and B2C return an error to SalesForce. The error will be in the SAML Response that AAD B2C returned to SalesForce. You can use a plugin like SAMLTracer to make it easier to find and read the SAML Request/Response.

Comment: That is a very helpful extension thank you for the recommendation. I am now able to see the error:

Application registered corresponding to IssuerUri "<Salesforce Entity Id>" in AuthRequest does not have assertion consumer service URL

Comment: So that error is saying the metadata in the App Reg manifest under metadataURL property, doesn’t contain an assertion consumer service URL. Maybe you have linked the incorrect sales force metadata there. Remember the app reg it’s targeting is an app reg that has an identifier uri matching the entityid in the SAML request. So make sure you’re even configuring the right App reg based on that first.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I integrated Salesforce as Service Provide against B2C as Idp. I did not try creating the app registration but instead I downloaded the Salesforce metadata and used it inside of my B2C policy like the code below.
Basically is the same but instead of save the Salesforce metadata(Login/Logout URIs) by registering a new application in B2C, I saved it in a XML file and pointed my B2C policy to use that metada.

```
<Metadata>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity">{Settings:B2C_SAML_PARTNER_ENTITY_SFE}</Item>
</Metadata>
```